# Rails Devise: get object of the currently logged in user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, devise

I've recently installed Devise on a rails application, and I am wondering if it is possible to get an instance of the currently logged in user in either one of the other models or controllers, and if so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Devise creates convenience methods on the fly that represent your currently logged user.

**However** you should note that the generated method name includes the class name of your user model. e.g. if your Devise model is called '`User`' then the currently logged in user can be accessed with '`current_user`', and if your Devise class is '`Admin`' then the logged in admin user can be accessed with '`current_admin`'.

There are a number of other methods created with similar conventions, for example '`user_signed_in?`' or again '`admin_signed_in?`', which are really nice.

These methods are available in controllers and views so you might have the following in a view:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <div>Signed in as... <%= current_user.email %></div>
<% end %>
```

Finally, if you are using two or more Devise models in your app (e.g. User and Admin), you can use the '`anybody_signed_in?`' convenience method to check if either of those types of user are signed in:

```
<% if anybody_signed_in? %>
  <h2>Special offers</h2>
  <p>All registered users will receive free monkeys!</p>
<% end %>
```

**Update:**

Since Devise version 1.2.0, '`anybody_signed_in?`' has been deprecated and replaced by '`signed_in?`'

Comment: Everything Scott says is correct, but also (and this may be new as well) Devise calls `user` and `admin` here "scopes". If you see that word in the documentation, that's what it's referring to.

Comment: But where in the request object is this info?

Answer (score 17):

The Devise helper methods are only available at the controller and view layers. They are not available at the model layer (see Controller filters and helpers section of [README](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#readme)).

- `Is it possible to get the currently logged in user from within a model?`.

It is not possible via the default helper methods that Devise creates for you. However, there are many alternative methods you can use to provide the `current_user` to a model. The simplest way has already been suggested by Alex Bartlow, and that is to simply pass the `current_user` via a method to your model.

- `Is it possible to get the currently logged in user from within a controllers?`

Yes it is possible. Use `current_<modelname>`, where `<modelname>` is the name of the model that has Devise authentication capabilities (i.e., via `rails g devise <modelname>`). If, for example, your model is `User`, then you would use `current_user`. If your model is `Elmo`, then you would use `current_elmo`.

Answer (score 1):

Pass it in as a parameter to the method call :).

One idea is to use `Thread.current[:current_user] = @current_user` as a before_filter - but if you're using a deployment stack like Thin + EM_Mysql2 + Rack::FiberPool, you'll need to set that to `Fiber.current[:current_user]`.

Those solutions are really just covering up for a lack of good design logic.

Comment: Personally I consider sticking contextual values onto the thread object to be a "smell". You acknowledge that in the last line, so kudos, but I just want to emphasize that...

Answer (score 1):

simple method is:

```
if @suit.user == current_user
```

example:

```
= link_to "Back", root_path, class: "btn btn-default"

  -if @suit.user == current_user

    = link_to "Edit", edit_suit_path, class: "btn btn-default"

    = link_to "Delete", suit_path, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-default"
```