# Rails How to get currently logged-in user object in model without passing it from the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, callback, devise

I'm using Devise 1.4.8

I want to assign the current logged-in user's *id* in callbacks method.

How to use current user's *id* in the model without passing it from the controller?

Is there any other way to do this in the model?

Comment: There is no way to access current_user in model. This is only available at controller level. What exactly you are trying to do with current_user in model?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149326/rails-devise-get-object-of-the-currently-logged-in-user

Comment: @Sush I want to assign the user_id column in the model(Product,..) before validation callbacks

Comment: then it is better to pass this from the controller. You can write some filter to assign that value to some global variable.

Comment: @Sush, but i'm trying to validate, Is the assigned value is belongs to the currently logged-in user and how can i validate without getting the logged-in user object inside the model instead of passing it from the controller??? is this good practice??

Comment: @CyleHunter thanks for your comment, i know its not possible to use Devise helper methods inside the model. I'm just looking to get the logged-in user object inside models by any new logic

Comment: just assign logged in user object(current_user) to some global variable let's say $var1, this $var1 can be accessible any where including model.

Comment: Thanks @Sush, Using global variable in production consumes lot memory and led to bad performance